Google Assistant Voice Control - App Name Mispronunciation
I'm developing an app called "Kwiklee" with Google Assistant integration using custom intents. The app’s name is pronounced "quickly." When I try using voice commands with Google Assistant, it interprets the name as "quickly" but doesn't trigger the app because of the spelling difference. The app is deployed to google play, currently in internal testing.
However, when I manually type "open Kwiklee and start measuring" it works fine. This seems to be purely a voice recognition issue.
I’m wondering if there is any there a way to configure phonetic app names or synonyms in shortcuts.xml so that Google Assistant recognizes and triggers the app when "quickly" is spoken? I didn't find anything about this in documentation.
Thanks in advance for your help!
